# "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" when attempting to calculate perimeter length

Tags: python

Using Python Script my predecessor left for processing stream survey data but am running into a "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" when attempting to process cross section survey data.

I've searched SO with no luck and am fairly new to Python so I'm not too sure how to approach solving this issue.

```
            #%% calculate perimeter length
            perim_m=[] 
            i=0
            while i<len(dataInputFile):
                perim_m.extend([math.sqrt((math.pow(sliceWd_m[i],2)+math.pow(htTri_m[i],2)))])
                i +=1
```

This cell block is part of a handful used to calculate the area of stream cross sections and the full track trace is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 4, in 
    perim_m.extend([math.sqrt((math.pow(sliceWd_m[i],2)+math.pow(htTri_m[i],2)))])

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The full set of blocks is below:

```
            #%% calculate adjusted cross section data
            distAdj_m=[]
            i=0
            while i<len(dataInputFile):
                distAdj_m.extend([dataInputFile.iloc[i,1]+horizAdj_m])
                i +=1

            elevAdj_m=[]
            i=0
            while i<len(dataInputFile):
                elevAdj_m.extend([dataInputFile.iloc[i,2]+vertAdj_m])
                i +=1

            #%% calculate total depth from datum
            depthDatum_m=[]
            i=0
            while i<len(dataInputFile):
                if stationRefElev_m-elevAdj_m[i]<=0:
                    depthDatum_m.extend([0])
                else:
                    depthDatum_m.extend([stationRefElev_m-elevAdj_m[i]])
                i +=1

            #%% calculate height triangle
            htTri_m=[0] #check that first value is Zero!
            i=1
            while i<len(dataInputFile):
                if elevAdj_m[i]>stationRefElev_m:
                    htTri_m.extend([0])
                else:
                    if depthDatum_m[i-1]==0:
                        htTri_m.extend([depthDatum_m[i]])
                    else:
                        if depthDatum_m[i]<depthDatum_m[i-1]:
                            htTri_m.extend([depthDatum_m[i-1]-depthDatum_m[i]])
                        else:
                            htTri_m.extend([depthDatum_m[i]-depthDatum_m[i-1]])
                i +=1

            #%% calculate height rectangle
            htRec_m=[0] #check that first value is Zero!
            i=1
            while i<len(dataInputFile):
                if stationRefElev_m-elevAdj_m[i]<=0:
                    htRec_m.extend([0])
                else:
                    if elevAdj_m[i]<elevAdj_m[i-1]:
                        htRec_m.extend([depthDatum_m[i-1]])
                    else:
                        htRec_m.extend([depthDatum_m[i]])
                i +=1

            #%% calculate slice width
            sliceWd_m=[0] #check that first value is Zero!
            i=1
            while i<len(dataInputFile):
                if stationRefElev_m-elevAdj_m[i]>0:
                    sliceWd_m.extend([distAdj_m[i]-distAdj_m[i-1]])
                else:
                    sliceWd_m.extend([0])
                i +=1

            #%% calculate perimeter length
            perim_m=[] 
            i=0
            while i<len(dataInputFile):
                perim_m.extend([math.sqrt((math.pow(sliceWd_m[i],2)+math.pow(htTri_m[i],2)))])
                i +=1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack, and Python! Typically this situation arises when you are converting between data types. Although your trace shows the error is here, perhaps it is being called from elsewhere? Are you using numpy somewhere? This would be a good place to start looking to see if the error is part of something bigger.

Comment: Thank you! I am using numpy but only with respect to reference elevations and distances - i.e.  stationRefElev_m=np.float_(refElev_m.loc[(refElev_m['Station']==int(station)) & (int(year)>=refElev_m['startDate']) & (int(year)<=refElev_m['endDate']),'refElev'])

Comment: No problem! I'm working on answering another question at the moment. I'll return here after. I think I know the answer for you, but I'll need to run on my machine to make sure. Look for my reply in (hopefully) less then 30 minutes.

Comment: Hi @poth.man, thanks for your patience. I unfortunately do not know the answer. But I wanted to leave a helpful video. I think the bigger issue is you're coming into someone else's code and trying to figure out what's going on. More specifically, I think this script uses variables from elsewhere in the script we cannot see, and has files that you may need to look into for a general idea of what is in them. With that said, I suggest checking out this awesome talk from PyData by James Powell https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mr2SE_drU5o. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input, @zerecees! I've been listening to this video as I've been working though this script error and appreciate you passing this along!